# Scala ProcessLogger & Future: How can I make sure all line callbacks are called BEFORE the onComplete block?

Tags: scala, concurrency, process, future

```
import scala.sys.process._
import scala.concurrent._ // (future)
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global // (future)

/* run "ls /opt"
 * which outputs 2 lines:
 *  - "X11"
 *  - "local"
 */
val command = Process(Seq("ls", "/opt"), None, "LANG" -> "")

val process = command.run(ProcessLogger(line => {
  Thread.sleep(1000) // slow execution down
  println(Thread.currentThread)
  println(line)
  println("")
}))

Future {
  process.exitValue // blocks until the process exits
}.onComplete { results =>
  println(Thread.currentThread)
  println("process exited: after last line callback finished?")
  println("DONE")
}
```

Output (order *as expected*, but is this always the case?):

```
Thread[Thread-47,5,run-main-group-0]
LINE X11

Thread[Thread-47,5,run-main-group-0]
LINE local

Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3,5,run-main-group-0]
process exited: after last line callback finished?
DONE
```

It seems o.k. because the `onComplete` block outputs its text *after line-related output is completely over*. But is this always the case? Who makes sure the different threads are run one after the other? **Can I rely on this supposed order?**

Answer (score 0):

> A Future is an object holding a value which may become available at
> some point. This value is usually the result of some other
> computation:
>
> 1. If the computation has not yet completed, we say that the Future is not completed.
> 2. If the computation has completed with a value or with an exception, we say that the Future is completed.
>
> Completion can take one of two forms:
>
> 1. When a Future is completed with a value, we say that the future was successfully completed with that value.
> 2. When a Future is completed with an exception thrown by the computation, we say that the Future was failed with that exception.
>
> The simplest way to create a future object is to invoke the future method which starts an asynchronous computation and returns a future holding the result of that computation. The result becomes available once the future completes.
>
> Note that Future[T] is a type which denotes future objects, whereas future is a method which creates and schedules an asynchronous computation, and then returns a future object which will be completed with the result of that computation.

[doc](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html)

You can see more implementation details at [github](https://github.com/scala/scala/tree/v2.10.1/src/library/scala/concurrent/impl)

Comment: From your quote I can extract: "`onComplete` is called after `process.exitValue` stops blocking". But how can I be sure the **process logger line callbacks** are not still executed *after* `process.exitValue` stops blocking and `onComplete` is called? I could not find anything about that in the docs.

Comment: in wich thread do you thing  "process logger line callbacks" are executed? you can see all threads in  java visual vm.